# Typo3 Powermail file upload resize filesize before upload

Tags: file, upload, typo3, size, powermail

How can I resize images within a Powermail Form? For example if I make a photo with a mobile phone, the image is about 4–6 MB, but I want to upload all images only within 800 x 600px and with a maximum size of 1 MB.

Is there a a way in Powermail?

Comment: If you want to *upload* it resized, the resizing would have to processed on your client. If you do not want oversized images on your webserver, maybe EXT:image_autoresize is an option for powermail's uploadfolder: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/image_autoresize/

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I've tried this extension, but it only works with uploads via the typo3 backend, not if I use the frontend form. Did I made something wrong?

Comment: There's also a Scheduler Task for recurring check for oversized images: https://docs.typo3.org/p/causal/image_autoresize/2.0/en-us/AdministratorManual/BatchProcessing/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *upload* it resized, the resizing would have to be processed on your client. That's (nearly) impossible to trigger via your website.

If you do not want oversized images on your webserver, maybe EXT:image_autoresize is an option for powermail's upload folder: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/image_autoresize
There's also a Scheduler Task for recurring check for oversized images.